# Centering button in mobile site

Tags: html, css

I have a Get in Touch button on the bottom of this page:

In the mobile version (less than 770px) of the site I would like it to be centered.

HTML:

```
<div class="white, home_contact_btn wpb_column vc_column_container vc_col-sm-4">
    <div class="wpb_wrapper">
        <a class="laborator-btn btn btn-index-1 btn-type-standard  contact-btn btn-primary btn-normal" target="" title="GET IN CONTACT" href="http://www.estiponagroup.com/dev/contact/">GET IN TOUCH</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.home_contact_btn a{
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An anchor is inherently an inline element and can be centered by applying `text-align:center;` to its parent element:

```
.wpb_wrapper{
    text-align:center;
}
```

Additionally, if you wanted it to be centered without targeting the parent, you can make the inline element display as a block level element and then center the text inside of it.

```
.home_contact_btn a{
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

And finally, if you have a certain width you want to have on the button, add that width and then you can use the auto-margins from your code.

```
.home_contact_btn a{
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    width:50%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set to the parent container text-align:center;

```
@media (max-width:700px){
.wpb_wrapper{
   text-align:center;

}
.home_contact_btn a{
    text-align:center;
}
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4egzgkvf/)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this :

```
.home_contact_btn a{
display : block;
text-align : center;
margin : 0 auto;
}
```

Alternatively, use this :

```
.wpb_wrapper {
text-align : center;
}
```

Both of them works, but I'll recommend you using the first option because in the second option all anchors (`<a>` elements) will be centered.

If you don't have any other anchor in the parent element of your 'Get in Touch' button, then second option will also work as expected.